# Why would a NodeJS/restify server *rarely* report EPERM on accept?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, error-handling

I'm running a restify server in NodeJS. On very rare occasions, on the order of 0.05% of HTTPS requests cause net.js to report the following error:

```
Error: accept EPERM
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:742:11)
    at TCP.onconnection (net.js:1280:24)
```

There is nothing special about the HTTP requests. Before this error is reported, the server may have serviced thousands of requests and even responded to dozens of identical requests. I have not been able to find any information about why a server might generate an EPERM error for a socket that has been successfully accepting connections for several hours.

By the way, this error occurs outside of any execution context of our source code. So it's not as if the EPERM is about our code accessing a file or performing some other system call. The EPERM is happening deep within the NodeJS TCP code when the new request arrives and before our code is invoked.

At first, when the error occurred it would cause NodeJS to terminate. So then I added code to catch application-level exceptions:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", onUncaughtException );
```

But since I don't know *why* this error is happening, it's not at all clear what is the recovery process.

Not sure if it will matter, but here is most of the code relevant to starting up the restify service:

```
var restify    = require("restify");
// skipping some other init code
// configuration data is read from a JSON file
var serverOptions = {
   name: configuration.server.name,
   version: configuration.server.version,
   formatters: {
      "application/json": jsonResponseFormatter,
      "text/html": textResponseFormatter
   },
   serverOptions.key: fs.readFileSync(configuration.server.sslKey),
   serverOptions.cert: fs.readFileSync(configuration.server.sslCert)
}
var server = restify.createServer( serverOptions );
// skipping middleware inits and URL registrations
server.listen(
     configuration.server.port, // using HTTPS 443
     configuration.server.serverip );
```

By the way, we are running an old version of NodeJS: v0.11.13. My long-term plan is to upgrade to the latest stable version, but we may not be able to update for a few months.

Comment: I've had EPERM errors happening when I had Nodemon reading folders that contained files it wasn't equipped to handle. Did you perhaps add any files or folders to your main server folder recently?

Comment: @WouldBe No, this EPERM error isn't related to any type of file system access. The error is being reported on the TCP/IP socket when an HTTP request is incoming.

Answer (score 1):

Let me leave my solution here in case anyone else stumbles across this same problem in the future.

Technically, I did not discover *why* this error was occurring, but I did find out how to handle the error condition successfully: trap and release. The error must be trapped at the application level because it is being generated deep within net.js outside any try-catch context of my source code. So if I don't trap it, then it will crash my application. But the error is non-fatal and it appears that it can be safely ignored. In testing, the socket continued to receive new connections even after this error occurred.

```
process.on("uncaughtException", onUncaughtException );
function onUncaughtException(error) {
  // put some code here to log the error occurrence, then ...
  if( error.code==="EPERM" && error.syscall==="accept" ) {
     // non-fatal error: do nothing; just ignore this error
  }
  else {
    // handle other application errors here
  }
}
```

So while it might still be interesting to know *why* a server socket can occasionally have an EPERM error, for now I'm satisfied knowing the proper way to handle the error when it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ man 2 accept
...
In addition, Linux accept() may fail if:

EPERM  Firewall rules forbid connection.
```

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what type of firewall rule would cause this error, all I can think of is that you may have a rule that allows incoming connections from a particular client but disallows outgoing data to that client's IP/network/port/...

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Robert. I'll have to investigate this idea. I would hope that our firewall configuration doesn't restrict connections on this port, but I have not checked it so it is possible.

Comment: @LeeJenkins it may be something obscure, given that it's only triggered occasionally. I would think that it has to do with the source-address of the client that's connecting (in other words, for traffic flowing _from_ your server _to_ a client). It would probably also help if you'd log the occasions when it happens, preferably with client info alongside.